# Sending an anonymous type with RenderPartial

Tags: model-view-controller, html-helper, anonymous-types

I am trying to send an anonymous type with RenderPartial but this method only allows me to
send (string, object , viewDataDictionary) or (string) or (string, object).

I am using MVC 1.0. Is there something I am missing here ?

Here is what I am trying to get workijng :

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ProductDisplay", product, new { DisplayAddToCartButton = false }); %>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ProductDisplay", product, (new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayAddToCartButton", false } })); %>
```